# Get the Url of the website we are calling from

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, httpcontext

I am trying to get the path of the current website and I am doing this to get the url.

```
Uri uri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
string callbackUrl  = uri.Scheme + "://" + uri.Host + (uri.IsDefaultPort ? "" : ":" + uri.Port) + "/Work";
```

It works fine on development server, but does not work in production which is a https site.

uri.Scheme gives me http. What am I doing wrong here. Is there a way that uri.Scheme returns https instead of http when this code is called from a https site.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIS does some filtering that affects Request.Url for https requests. Ended up doing some Googling and it seems like there are a few limitations. You might have to come up with a custom solution based on [this](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/08/05/adding-httpsssl-support-to-aspnet-mvc-routing/) blog post.

Comment: thanks for the link Nadir. I have this code in couple of projects now and some of them are not mvc. Is there a way to know if I am in a secured https site or unsecured http

Comment: Just tried that, but Request.IsSecureConnection is returning false in production i.e. https site.

Comment: The entire website doesn't have to be https. I'd make sure the website is configured as it should be.

Comment: It is a secure site but Request.IsSecureConnection is returning false. I am not sure why. May be something to do with its setup on the server. I will look into it. Thank you for your help. I appreciate it.